# how to compress javascript files served from my rails app running on apache/passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm using Apache 2.2, Passenger 3.0.2, Rails 3.

I've managed to compress the css file by modifying the deflate.conf file. However, when I run the firefox addon yslow, it still says the javascript files are uncompressed.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
          AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/javascript text/javascript application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

Above, I'm using all three variants: "application/javascript text/javascript application/x-javascript" but no luck.

Here's the message from yslow:

> Grade D on Compress components with
>   gzip
>
> There are 3 plain text components that
>   should be sent compressed
>
> ```
> * http://myhost.dyndns.org:8080/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js?...
> * http://myhost.dyndns.org:8080/javascripts/jquery.validate.min.js?...
> * http://myhost.dyndns.org:8080/javascripts/rails.js?...
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Jammit is an industrial strength asset packaging library for Rails, providing both the CSS and JavaScript concatenation and compression that you'd expect, as well as YUI Compressor and Closure Compiler compatibility, ahead-of-time gzipping, built-in JavaScript template support, and optional Data-URI / MHTML image and font embedding.

http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @fretje - Isn't your comment a little on the hypercritical side... given the content is a href only. I fluffed up my answer just for you anyway ;)

Comment: That was the intention... an href only is frowned upon here (that link in my comment is just easier both for you en me to explain/understand that). And I can assure you you didn't do it just for me... but for everyone reading your answer after me. The community thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using capistrano, add a deployment task that compresses our javascript files in-place on the production server.

Check this:
http://blog.jcoglan.com/2007/05/26/make-capistrano-compress-your-javascript-and-css-automatically/